# Sequelize insert in multiple tables with associations (cascading)

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a model with cascading association such as:
Surveys > Questions > Options

Survey has many Questions
Question has many Options

When I create a survey I want to create questions with options. 
ex object:

```
survey = {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        Questions:[
          {
            question_type: 'Radio',
            question: 'q1',
            Options:[
              {
                option: 'o1'
              },
              {
                option: 'o2'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

When I create using the option below I get error.

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined
```

My create looks like this

```
 models.Survey.create(survey,{
          include:  [models.Question,{include: [models.Option]}]
        }).then(function() {
      reply({success:1});
    });
```

Table scema

Question:

```
QuestionId
SurveyId
```

I also have another question. If I remove the "Option" association it inserts Questions but it is entering the "NULL" as SurveyId after "Survey" creation.

Comment: are you sure Survey is defined?

Comment: i get same issue right now. Did you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's connecting association error. Try it:

```
models.Survey.create(survey, {
    include: [{
        model: models.Question, 
        include: [models.Option]
    }]
}).then(function() {
    reply({success:1});
});
```

Comment: Thank you Tilov. The second include seems to do the trick. However, when the question is inserted for the Survey the Id seems to be null. For ex: INSERT INTO `Surveys` (`id`,`title`,`description`) VALUES (NULL,'title','');

INSERT INTO `Questions` (`id`,`question_type`,`question`,`SurveyId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'Radio','q1',NULL);

INSERT INTO `Options` (`id`,`option`,`QuestionId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'o1',7);

INSERT INTO `Options` (`id`,`option`,`QuestionId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'o2',7);